# Batch file to iterate folder and sub-folders from current date to past 5 date and push sync files to FTP from network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to write a batch script to iterate folders and sub-folders from last five days and push file to FTP from network drive.
So far I am able to get 5 days previous date and current date and able to push file to FTP.

But not able to find out the solution to iterate over last 5 days folders and sub-folders inside that.

```
@echo off

REM get current date
set TIMESTAMP=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%

REM get 5 days previous date from current date
set day=-5
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "pre_date=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%pre_date:~0,4%"
set "MM=%pre_date:~4,2%"
set "DD=%pre_date:~6,2%"
set "pre_date=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"

REM synchronize folder from network drive to FTP
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\batch\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://team:O%%l%%24og3@187.121.11.25/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 256 f0pa/Fxg81I0Wjo=""" ^
    "synchronize remote Z:\test\folder1 /mnt/logs/test" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

PAUSE
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

FOLDER STRUCTURE-

date folder(folder name only date) --> multiple sub-folders --> then some sub-folders are having files AND some sub-folders again having sub-folders. Only first folder having name as date not sub-folders.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of WinSCP [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) to generate a [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) to filter the synchronization to the folders you want:

```
%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%/;%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyy-mm-dd%/;%TIMESTAMP-2D#yyyy-mm-dd%/;%TIMESTAMP-3D#yyyy-mm-dd%/;%TIMESTAMP-4D#yyyy-mm-dd%/;%TIMESTAMP-5D#yyyy-mm-dd%/
```

The whole `synchronize` command will be like:

```
    "synchronize remote Z:\test\folder1 /mnt/logs/test -filemask=%%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%%/;%%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyy-mm-dd%%/;%%TIMESTAMP-2D#yyyy-mm-dd%%/;%%TIMESTAMP-3D#yyyy-mm-dd%%/;%%TIMESTAMP-4D#yyyy-mm-dd%%/;%%TIMESTAMP-5D#yyyy-mm-dd%%/" ^
```

(note the doubled `%`, due to batch file syntax)

---

And now you do not need any of your "date calculation" code.

---

If you want the number of days to be variable, you can generate the mask in a loop:

```
set DAYS=5
for /l %%D in (0, 1, %DAYS%) do call set MASK=%%MASK%%;%%%%TIMESTAMP-%%DD#yyyy-mm-dd%%%%/
set MASK=%MASK:~1%
```

```
    "synchronize remote Z:\test\folder1 /mnt/logs/test -filemask=%MASK%" ^
```

---

If you really need to loop over the days, because you have specific directory structure requirements, you can do:

```
set DAYS=5
for /l %%D in (0, 1, %DAYS%) do (

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
    /log="C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\batch\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
    /command ^
      "open sftp://team:O%%l%%24og3@187.121.11.25/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 256 f0pa/Fxg81I0Wjo=""" ^
      "synchronize remote Z:\%%TIMESTAMP-%%DD#yyyy-mm-dd%%\folder1 /mnt/logs/%%TIMESTAMP-%%DD#yyyy-mm-dd%%/test ^
      "exit"
)
```

If you do not want to connect for every date, you can generate the `synchronize` commands in the loop only. And execute them at once using one connection (one `WinSCP.com` call) at the end.